# Sequel Pro takes forever to load a database on Mac

Tags: macos, sequel-pro

So I've got this issue since I first installed the app. I don't know what's wrong. It just gets stuck saying `loading database 'db'`. what should I do?

Then sometimes it gives this error:

```
3 Feb 2019 at 11:31:25 PM: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client:
dispatch source activated with no event handler set; 
set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sequel Pro has [known issues with MySQL 8](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3AMySQL-8.0+)